# Python Ingestion Table with Hyphen

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to ingest a table from SQL Server into Snowflake.

The table is named something similar to this:

```
table20-21
```

I am using the Pandas library.

```
data_frame = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection)
```

Before declaring the dataframe, I did `print(query)` and `print(connection)` and both of those return valid values.

Does `read_sql_query` not like tables with hyphens in the table name?

**Edit #1:**

Query being used:

```
 query = ' SELECT top 100 * FROM db.tst_schema.table20-21'
```

I'm currently trying to play around with the ".format" method.

```
table_name = "table20-21"

query = ' Select top 100 * from db.tst_schema'{}'".format(table_name)
```

Is this the correct approach or does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: Nothing to do with `read_sql_query` and everything to do with SQL Server syntax: you need `[]` brackets `SELECT top 100 * FROM db.tst_schema.[table20-21]`

Comment: Let me try playing with this. Thank you

Comment: My man, it worked. Post this as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose (*delimit*) such identifiers in brackets `[]`

```sql
SELECT top 100 * FROM db.tst_schema.[table20-21]
```

[This is documented on the MSDN site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15#rules-for-regular-identifiers)